# Corrosion due to dissimilar metals or bad ground?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water

I'm a 1st time home owner but experienced DIYer here. Unfortunately I have little plumbing experience. I installed a hot water recirc. pump at my hot water heater about a month ago. I did not notice any leaks, but this morning noticed corrosion at the fittings and on the case (see pics). Could there be a bad ground where the pump plugs in or could it be due to dissimilar metals?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this isn't due to a pinhole leak?  Because I see liquid-flow paths...  Condensation maybe?

Comment: Haven't noticed any condensation. It's possible there is a pinhole leak but would a tiny amount of water on the fittings cause this? It's just copper and brass right?

Comment: I see paths that appear to be left by mineral deposits in flowing liquid. Try taking an eyedropper and wetting the pipe and see if water follows the already-indicated paths.  If so, it is water action.  That's not to say corrosion isn't playing its part.

Comment: Interesting. If it's mineral deposit due to water flow, then should be an easy fix, probably just redo the fitting connections. I'm assuming that the green is color is just oxidized copper leached into the water sitting on the fitting?

Comment: Yeah now that I look at it closer, it looks like that seal is leaking very slowly, bubbling up around that fitting etc. Maybe the mineral content plugged the hole.

Comment: In the top picture, I looks like you might have the same situation starting to happen? Or my eyes are just bad and it's solder, but I don't think so.

Comment: No solder, it's all threaded connections.